# Time conflict detection in VB.Net MySQL logic glitch

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 2 time range named as funtime and funtime1 (start time and end time) in the database.

Lets assume these two time sets.
8:00 am  - 9:00 am and
9:00 am - 10:00 am

Logically, there's no conflict. However in my code.. it recognize as conflict..
Here is my code:

```
Dim str As String = "select * from tbl_funeral where date_burial = '" & t8.Text & "' and (('" & funtime.Text & "' between funtime and funtime1 ) or ( '" & funtime1.Text & "' between funtime and funtime1 ))"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds)
    dt = ds.Tables(0)
    Try
        If (dt.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
            MsgBox("There is a conflict on " & t8.Text & " at " & funtime.Text & "!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Conflict")
        Else
            'AddSchedule()
            add()

            MsgBox("Scheduling was successful, would you like set more schedule?", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
            rpt1.Show()
            srt1.Text = "  "
            clearall()
            con.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

are there any ways to make it work properly? what i do for the meantime is putting 9:01 am instead of 9:00 am so that it wont conflict. thanks~!

Comment: You are unlikely to get dates or times to act **as** dates and times by storing the as text.  `"9:00"` (text) simply wont evaluate the same way that `9:00` (a time) will

Comment: so what should i do? should i change the datatype?

Comment: you shoiuld a) **not** concat strings to create SQL, use parameters, b) dispose of those DB Provider objects as needed, c) use typed data - a time would be a TimeSpan, d) change the DB to match